# How to move 'add document' to the top of the library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I want to move the 'add document' button to the top.
For Reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c5dq.jpg
Please Advise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is my question unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the code below into a content editor web part in list view page to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idHomePageNewDocument").closest("table").after($(".ms-listviewtable"));
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT, do you know how to change the length of promoted links?

Comment: Check the link here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26522.sharepoint-2013-promoted-links-change-size-wrap-view-handle-click-event-using-jquery.aspx